# impossible to terminate function (>500 000s of execution)

Tags: google-apps-script

I've built automation on apps script. I have a trigger that runs every minute and the automation was working well for one week. Suddenly, I had an execution that wasn't stopping and it's still impossible to terminate it[image]. (see picture) I have an error message when I'm on the dashboard and try to kill it. The automation uses API technology and Jdbc connections

Do you have any clue how to terminate it? It's burning all my daily quota of execution time.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the textual error message that you get?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to https://script.google.com
2. Click on My Executions
3. Find your script
4. Right click over your script and select Terminate

Comment: Hi Rubén! Thanks for the answer! I think I was not clear enough about my issue.

I already tried to terminate with this way and it's at this moment that I have an error. 
The picture from the post is from My Executions page :)

Comment: @JulienSchryve please edit the question to add all the relevant details to it.

Comment: Same issue here. I terminate the execution, I get a confirmation message "The process has been terminated", but as I refresh the page the execution still running (and the total time counter is going up).
This also makes impossible for me to start the debugger.

Comment: @FrancoSF How do you know that the process is still running? I suggest you to post a new question including all the relevant details (including the answer to my clarification question) b/c Julien didn't update the OP.

Comment: @Rubén I just posted a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65725910/how-to-force-the-termination-of-a-google-apps-script

I know the execution still running because the execution time keeps going up and the debugger refuses to start.