# How to force the termination of a Google Apps Script

Tags: debugging, google-apps-script, ide

Something went wrong on one of my last debug session with Google Apps Script (don't know what). Since then, I'm not able to run a debugger anymore. The debugger refuses to start.

[image]

When i checked the Execution Report/page I noticed all my debugging sessions are still running. I tried to terminate them by selecting the 3-dots menu on the right and the Terminate command (for every single process).

[image: Execution Report]

Apparently the process/execution was terminated, I even received a confirmation:

[image: Process Terminated]

But, as I refresh the page, all the executions are still up and running.

I posted an issue on the Google IssueTracker, but so far no answer. Other people have posted the same issue, but so far nobody has received an answer from Google.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177450621

P.S. I'm not using triggers.

Comment: Try 1. Open your project in incognito mode, using a different browser, using a different computer. 2. Go back to the old IDE then comeback to the new IDE.

Comment: Thank you. I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: `But, as I refresh the page, all the executions are still up and running.` And you were able to terminate again?

Comment: I tried to terminate them again without success. The good news is that the Debugger now works again. I guess I can just forget about those executions.

Comment: Debugger is again blocked... This is a kind of a stressful situation when combined with a deadline.

Comment: Can you reference the issue you filed in Issue Tracker?

Comment: I added the link to my post.